# Is it possible to use the map function on an array of jsx items?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, hamburger-menu

I am new to React and not entirely sure how to go about setting some things up:

I have a top navigation menu which turns into a hamburger menu for mobile devices. In order to define menu items only once, I thought it would be a good idea to extracted them into an array of jsx items and use the array for both types of menus:

```
        export default function Navigation () {
        const MenuItems = [                
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>,
                        <Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link>,
                        <Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link>,
                        <Link to="/page3">Page 3</Link>
                    ];
        const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 767px)' });
        const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 1224px)' });
    
        return (
            <Nav role='navigation'>
                { isMobile && <BurgerMenu MenuItems={ MenuItems } />}
                { isDesktop && 
                    <ul>
                        { MenuItems.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{ item }</li>) }
                    </ul>
                }           
            </Nav>
        );
    }
```

I'm using react-burger-menu for the hamburger menu:

```
export default function BurgerMenu({ MenuItems }) {
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => { setMenuOpen(false); };

    return(
       <Menu 
           isOpen={ menuOpen }
           onStateChange={({isOpen}) => setMenuOpen(isOpen)}
           right 
           width={ '254px' } 
           customBurgerIcon={ <img src={ burger } /> }
           customCrossIcon={ <img src={ close } /> }
           styles={ styles }
       >
           { MenuItems.map(( item ) => item ) }
       </Menu>
   );
}
```

The problem is that because there's no onClick event handler on the menu items inside the burger menu, it never closes when clicking on one of the menu items. Since this is an array of jsx items I can't directly modify the items using the map function.

1. Is there a way to use my array and somehow inject the click event handler into each item (without converting it to a string)? Turning it into its own component would not allow me to then wrap each item with an *li* tag for desktop display.
2. I purposefully tried to avoid using an array of objects for this, but seems like this might be the best way to solve my problem?

I'm mainly just trying to understand if there are ways to approach this which I haven't thought about. Any insights or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a slightly different approach. Put data about your menu items in the array, and only create the components when you actually map over them. This would also give you some additional flexibility going forward.

```
function Navigation() {
  const MenuItems = [
    {
      to: "/",
      title: "Home",
    },
    {
      to: "/page1",
      title: "Page 1",
    },
    {
      to: "/page2",
      title: "Page 2",
    },
    {
      to: "/page3",
      title: "Page 3",
    }
  ];
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 767px)' });
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 1224px)' });

  return (
    <Nav role='navigation'>
      {isMobile && <BurgerMenu MenuItems={MenuItems} />}
      {isDesktop &&
        <ul>
          {MenuItems.map((item, index) => <li key={index}><Link to={item.to}>{item.title}</Link></li>)}
        </ul>
      }
    </Nav>
  );
}
```

This gives you the flexibility to add additional props to your items in the `BurgerMenu` component:

```
function BurgerMenu({ MenuItems }) {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => { setMenuOpen(false); };

  return (
    <Menu
      isOpen={menuOpen}
      onStateChange={({ isOpen }) => setMenuOpen(isOpen)}
      right
      width={'254px'}
      customBurgerIcon={<img src={burger} />}
      customCrossIcon={<img src={close} />}
      styles={styles}
    >
      {MenuItems.map((item) => <Link to={item.to} onClick={handleClick}>{item.title}</Link>)}
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

I noticed this in your question

> I purposefully tried to avoid using an array of objects for this

But I'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind it. I think this is the best approach here, and might go so far to say it's the best approach most of the time.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to create the same mapping in two different locations (I used a simplified version here, but my menu is a little bit more complex) and since I'm also new to React, it was really refreshing to use jsx this way. So I was trying to understand if there was a way to make this work, and whether it's even a thing.

I upvoted your comment but I don't have enough reputation for it to show. Thanks for steering me in the right direction though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the items with divs and adding `onClick` to them?

```
{ MenuItems.map(( item ) => <div onClick={handleClick}>{item}</div> ) }
```

Comment: Semantically I think this is probably not best practice. This would have worked with an unordered list, but I believe react-burger-menu expects menu items as its direct children.